# Manually Install tikz.sty

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows)

I have MiKTeX 2.9. My questions is my Latex prompts me to install tikz.sty from the package pgf however its automatic install cannot seem to find the package, so I manually went to install it. Now I have found the file that I am looking for (tikz.sty) however I do not know how to install it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello guys, I solved the problem from this link http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2063/how-can-i-manually-install-a-package-on-miktex-windows Obtaining and installing packaged universal archives: However it prompted a new problem, although I pasted all the required files into its proper directories, when I run my Latex file, it still says the file is missing. And this is even after I updated with Refresh FNDB

Comment: MikTeX really should be able to install PGF/TikZ through the package manager. Generally there is no need to install packages manually. Even if automatic installs are broken, you can still run the package manager (mpm.exe) manually.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the source of the problem. You are right, when it auto-installed, I did not look up to see the problem. The problem I think is pdflatex.EXE: Windows API error 5: Access is denied. And thus did not allow me to install. When I run MikTeX with admin rights, it no longer prompts me to install the tikz.sty file.